# 架空のLinuxコマンドの出力値から必要なものだけを取り出す方法。

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

あるLinuxのコマンドで"imagestatus"というのがあったと仮定してください。
そのコマンドに画像ファイル（拡張子：jpg）を引数で渡すと以下のような値を出力します：

```
File: sampleimg.jpg
Resolution: 720 x 547
Channels: 3
Channel Types: RGB without Alpha
```

これを"File": "Resolution"にして以下のようなフォーマットに直したいのです。

```
sampleimg.jpg: 720 x 547
```

imagestatsusに付けられるoptionが分からない前提で出力値から必要なものだけを取り出すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awkで良ければ`awk '{FS=": "}{ if($1 ~ "File|Resolution") {print $2} }'`のように書けます。

FS(フィールド区切り文字)で"File"と"sampleimg.jpg"を`$1`と`$2`に格納し、
if文の正規表現で`$1`の抽出対象を判別して`$2`を出力します。
awkは改行区切りで出力するので、下記のサンプルコードては最後にsedで整形しています。

```
echo "File: sampleimg.jpg
Resolution: 720 x 547
Channels: 3
Channel Types: RGB without Alpha" | \
awk '{FS=": "}{ if($1 ~ "File|Resolution") {print $2} }' | sed -z '0,/\n/ s/\n/: /'
#sampleimg.jpg: 720 x 547
```

Comment: 仮にimagestatusに複数の画像ファイルを渡せたとして(例：imagestatus *.png)、その時に特定のresolution(例：2048 x 1556)を持つものだけを「"File": "Resolution"」のフォーマットで出力したい場合はどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: ご質問とコメントの追記で要求が大きく変わっていますので、別の質問を作成されることをお勧めします。[別質問の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/85933/9820)とこの回答を組み合わせて応用することでコメントの処理は実現できそうですが、試行錯誤してもうまく動かないならば想定されるimagestatusからの出力と、試したawkコマンドを質問文に記載すると的確な回答を得やすくなります。